# genome diagram fail: Unicode Decode Error

Tags: python, unicode, decode, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to get the genome diagram function of biopython to work but it currently fails.
This is the output, i'm not sure what the error means. Any suggestions?

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_partial_diagram (test_GenomeDiagram.DiagramTest)
construct and draw SVG and PDF for just part of a SeqRecord.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_GenomeDiagram.py", line 662, in test_partial_diagram
assert open(output_filename).read().replace("\r\n", "\n") \
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/codecs.py", line 300, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data file is composed of bytes which are encoded is some encoding other than `utf-8`. You need to specify the right encoding.

```
 open(output_filename, encoding=...)
```

There is no entirely reliable way for us to tell you what encoding it should be. But since

```
In [156]: print('\x93'.decode('cp1252'))
“
```

(and since the quotation mark is a pretty common character) you might want to try using

```
open(output_filename, encoding='cp1252')
```

on line 662 of test_GenomeDiagram.py.

Answer (score 0):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable byte encoding.  In cases where a character is being encoding that requires multiple bytes, the second an subsequent bytes are of the form `10xxxxxx` and no initial bytes (or single byte characters) have this form.  As such, 0x93 cannot ever be the first byte of a UTF-8 character.  The error message is telling you that your buffer contains an invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.